# Why do mock annotations not mock/inject a repository?

Tags: java, testing, dependency-injection, mockito

I am using mockito to test a controller. That controller uses a repository that connects to database. I want to mock userRepository and inject it in usercontroller, but when I run the test a NullPointerException is thrown at `when(userRepository.addUser(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);` in the test. Also when I removed this line to see whether mockMvc also gives this error and indeed it did just that.

Thus I think the problem causer is the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` that it somehow doesn't enable the annotations.

I did some research about why this is happening on Google but none of the solutions solved this problem and I don't know why this is not working.

**My Controller that I want to test:**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private transient userRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/user/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        String firstname = user.getUsername();
        String lastname = user.getLastName();

        boolean added = userRepository.addUser(firstname , lastname );

        if(added){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
```

**My test so far**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(userController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void testAddUserToDb() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        User.setFirstName("first");
        User.setLastName("last");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String request = gson.toJson(user);

        //HERE I GET NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
        when(userRepository.addUser(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(post("user/add")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(request))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));


        verify(userRepository, times(1)).addUser(anyString(), anyString());
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(userRepository);
    }
```

**My user repository:**

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private transient JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public boolean addUser(String firstName, String lastName){
        boolean added = false;

        String ADD_USER = "INSERT INTO Users(firstName, lastname) VALUES(?, ?)";

        //execute sql query and retrieve result set
        int rowsHit = jdbcTemplate.update(ADD_USER, firstName, lastName);

        if (rowsHit == 1) {
            added = true;
        }

        return added;
    }
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at server.controller.UserControllerTest.testAddUserToDb(UserControllerTest.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Comment: You're mixing Mockito annotations, for unit tests, with Spring annotations, for Spring integration tests. Remove `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. Replace `@MockBean` by `@Mock`.

Comment: I get following error:



```
Mockito cannot mock this class: class UserRepository.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class UserRepository.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
```

Comment: Not sure why you get this error. But also, remove the version number from your mockito dependency. Use the version that Spring Boot recommends (by not specifying the version number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your test class to the code below and it should not throw any `NullPointerException` anymore (though you have some other compile-time errors in your code, like in the controller mixing `firstname` with `username`).

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testAddUserToDb() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("first");
        user.setLastName("last");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String request = gson.toJson(user);

        //HERE I GET NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
        when(userRepository.addUser(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(post("user/add")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(request))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));


        verify(userRepository, times(1)).addUser(anyString(), anyString());
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(userRepository);
    }
}
```

In your gradle file you are mixing Spring (Boot) versions and some other, transient dependencies of Spring. Could you also update your Gradle file to this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 12

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'

    components {
        withModule('org.springframework:spring-beans') {
            allVariants {
                withDependencyConstraints {
                    it.findAll { it.name == 'snakeyaml' }.each { it.version { strictly '1.19' } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'server.Application'
}
```

If you'll get Exceptions complaining about a datasource, then remove `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'` from the Gradle configuration (or import a datasource dependency and configure it in Gradle, if you are using a database).

Comment: :/ I am still getting the same error. I also changed username to firstname now

Comment: Hmm, you run exactly this piece of code? Are you sure that it's the same error?

Comment: Yes exactly your code. Can this be because of a problem in build.gradle file?

Comment: Hm, yeah maybe.. but the test runs up until that point where it hits the `NullPointerException`, so I kind of doubt that it's a problem in the gradle file. How do you run the test? From an IDE? And I take it that your test file structure is in `src/test/java/some/example/package/UserControllerTest.java` ?

Comment: I run test from Intellij IDE and yes that is how the path looks like to the test.

Comment: Okay, that means we both did the same thing (I also ran it from IntelliJ). The only difference is that I used Maven instead of Gradle. Is it possible for you to edit the question with your Gradle file content added to it?

Comment: Ok added my build gradle

Comment: Updated my answer with some Gradle file edits. Hope this will help you get it working!